# Setting dropEffect and effectAllowed in dragstart not taking effect immediately

Tags: javascript, html

jsfiddle illustrating my problem, notice the slight flickr of a plus sign below the cursor when starting to drag:

http://jsfiddle.net/nWLdx/

Okay so the problem is that when I drag I am setting the dropEffect and effectAllowed in the dragstart event. However there is still a slight flickr of a plus sign appearing below the cursor. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
    $element.bind('dragstart', function (event) {
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
        console.log("dragstart");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

What browser do you see this behvaiour on ? I'm not seeing it.

The effectAllowed is a set of possible operations to be performed on drop, you set the effectAllowed on dragStart and you set the dropEffect on dragover.